# Parse - two installations with the same deviceToken (iOS)

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform

Problem: I'm getting two push notifications to the same device, due to multiple installations sharing the same deviceToken.

I have an application that has a channel for every user identifier in my system. This allows me to send a push message to this user and have him receive it from all of his devices.

According to this post: https://parse.com/questions/does-parse-enforce-uniqueness-on-devicetoken-across-installation-objects

the same device (deviceToken) will never have two installations, which makes sense.

However, I have recently updated my parse iOS SDK (to 1.2.19) and suddenly when upgrading an application on an iOS device where it was already installed, my application creates an extra installation on the parse server, with the same deviceToken (!) (verified by querying this token in the data browser).

This causes the device to get my push message twice which is very bad.

Note: When switching to the new SDK, another new problem occurred, which caused the setDeviceToken function which I used with the previous SDK (which receives a string token), to stop working. Forcing me to switch to: setDeviceTokenFromData instead. This might be related.

What can I do? This effectively means I cannot upload a new version of my app.

Comment: I would create a "Job" that checks for duplicate installations and deletes the older one.  Or perhaps more thorough to parse the installations together.

Comment: Thanks, that is a valid solution, but before I go there, I'm trying to understand if this happens because I'm doing something wrong, or because Parse has a bug (perhaps related to the new SDK, or different API I use). Naturally, I would be happy if there is a way to solve this without having to implement this kind of job (specially since I use Parse only for push notifications, and wouldn't want to put too much effort there).

Comment: I can't say if its a bug in the system or not.  To prevent future duplicates, you could use a cloud code `afterSave` and validate it that way.  That might also be more than you're looking to do though.

Comment: At the moment it sounds like the next best thing after actually solving the problem and not creating duplicates (by finding what I'm doing wrong or having Parse solve it if it's on their side), is dealing with the symptom like you suggest (though I've never used cloud code, so I'm just guessing): Upon "afterSave" of an installation, get the deviceToken from it, and query old Installation objects with the same device token, and delete them first. I'll wait a bit for other suggestions.

Comment: If you update your app, a device that installs the update should get from Apple the same device token the previous version had. What you describe implies that Parse doesn't recognize the new version is an installation of the same app on the same device. I am sure they got this case covered. You must be using their API in a wrong way. Unfortunatelly I can't tell you what you are doing wrong (since I'm not familier with their API, and you didn't supply any code anyway).

Comment: Thanks Eran. I believe code won't help here because I'm using the exact step by step code they provide in their guide, which is quite short, and it "sort of" works in the sense that I can create an installation, and send push notifications. My previous usage was also exactly as they have guided a year ago which is (unfortunately) the last time I've updated the SDK. That's why I suspect the problem is caused either from updating the SDK, or from switching to registering the deviceToken with parse using setDeviceTokenFromData, instead of from string.

Comment: I am also having this issue. It also began happening when I updated the Parse SDK and switched to setDeviceTokenFromData. In my case it happens after the user updates the app and then changes the push channels on the installation and saves it. 1.) Can someone suggest the best way to create a "Job" to remove the duplicates (as Logan suggested). Sample code would be appreciated. 2.) Can someone from Parse weigh in and confirm that this is or is not a Parse bug? According to the link provided by the OP Parse is supposed to enforce only one installation per deviceToken.

Comment: @James, you can use this code as reference: http://pastebin.com/zrF6RsiZ [disclaimer: it was written by someone that no longer works at our company, so it comes with absolutely no warranty :) ]